# MongoDB C# driver query operators in QueryDocument or $not $size alternative

Tags: c#, mongodb

I couldn't quite find something like this, hence the question. I have a page\blarg collection that has an array of Categories. I'd like to be able to pull a list of existing categories and I don't want to do a Map Reduce so I decided I would just pull all of the categories and then filter them for uniqueness client side. I'd like to only pull arrays that are not empty, though, so I devised the following query:

{ Categories : { $not { $size : 0 } } }

However I don't know how to replicate it using the driver. $Not takes a BsonValue and $Size just takes an int, I'm not sure how to put a $Size condition in the $Not query. I figured I could use a QueryDocument or something but i'm not sure how to emulate operators via anonymous objects (or at least I haven't seen any documentation on it).

P.S. I realize I might be able to do an Query.EQ("Categories", BsonArray.Create(new List())) or something but I'm interested in the answer for the principle of it at this point, I can think of another scenario where I might want any arrays in which there is more or less than one entry for instance.

Comment: The best way is to do filtering on client side. Because server is single, but clients are multiple. So we should shift all hard tasks to the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express your query in C# as follows:

var query = Query.Not("Categories").Size(0);

You can verify that it is in fact the same query with:

var json = query.ToJson();

Comment: Thank you! I just didn't dig deep enough. I got stuck on trying to use Query.NE